# How to drop UITableViewCell to bottom of UITableView.

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

A UITableView which have UITableViewCell of 20 rows, each row do have one button on it, click button I want to drop the UITableViewCell to bottom to UITableView.

Is there any delegate method which do for it.
Your feedback will be appreciated.

Comment: can u show ur code with button action

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a method on tableview

```
- (void)moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
               toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)newIndexPath
```

You can read more https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is one!

Use below delegate methods for that:

have to return `YES` to allow moving of tableView row in `canMoveRowAtIndexPath` delegate method as per your requirement,

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == 0) // Don't move the first row
      return NO;

   return YES;
}
```

Then, use `moveRowAtIndexPath` delegate method to Updating the data-model array for the relocated row accordingly,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath 
      toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath 
{

      //Updating the data-model array
}
```

Like `moveRowAtIndexPath` in button click,

```
- (void)btnClick:(UIButton*)sender
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)sender.superview;
    NSIndexPath *indexpath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    //Change accordindly as per requirement 
    [tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:indexpath.row inSection:indexpath.section] toIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:indexpath.section]];

}
```

Also, read Apple documentation for same:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageReorderRow/ManageReorderRow.html